# ng-repeat dropdownlist gets selected on the time edit

Tags: jquery, html, angular

I want default aoption in ng-repeat dropdownlist like "Please select" at zero index.

and also when we edit the record from database then the dropdown should display the save one as selected .

Here is the HTML page code:

```
<select  ng-model="DataUploadModel.ReportTypeId" class="inp w100">
                <option value="0" label="Please Select"></option>
                <option repeat-end="onEnd()" ng-repeat="lst in ReportList" value="{{lst.ID}}">
                   {{lst.ReportTypeName}}
                </option>
            </select>
```

Here is the controllerjs code:

```
APIInterface.GetRecordWithoutParam(EndPoint.Admin, apiRoute.StockReportList, function (response) {
        if (response.isSuccess) {
            $scope.ReportList = response.result._ReportTypeResponse;
        }
        else {
            $scope.ErrorData.errorMessage = response.message;
            $scope.ErrorData.isError = true;
            HideLoader();
        }}, function (err) { HideLoader(); });
```

Thanks
Ritesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if below code works.

You can generate select options using `ngOptions`, It will also select the value specified in `ng-model` (if don't want any value set by default just set `$scope.DataUploadModel = { ReportTypeId:  '' };`

For placeholder like `please select` empty option with value as black will work.

P.S. To make it work, have added hardcoded values to `ReportList'

HTML :

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <select ng-options="rpt.ID as rpt.ReportTypeName for rpt in ReportList" ng-model="DataUploadModel.ReportTypeId">
     <option value="">Please select</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

JS :

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.DataUploadModel = {
    ReportTypeId: 2
  };
 $scope.ReportList = [{
   ID: 1,
   ReportTypeName: "name1"
 }, {
   ID: 2,
   ReportTypeName: "name2"
 }];
}
```

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PrashantShirke/ADukg/11984/).

**UPDATE:**

Read `Choosing between ngRepeat and ngOptions` section of [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) link.

> In many cases, ngRepeat can be used on  elements instead of ngOptions to achieve a similar result.
>
> However, ngOptions provides some benefits:
>
> - more flexibility in how the 's model is assigned via the select as part of the comprehension expression
> - reduced memory consumption by not creating a new scope for each repeated instance
> - increased render speed by creating the options in a documentFragment instead of individually
>
> Specifically, select with repeated options slows down significantly starting at 2000 options in Chrome and Internet Explorer / Edge.

But still if you want to use `ng-repeat` then you can use `ng-selected` like below.

```
 <select ng-model="DataUploadModel.ReportTypeId" class="inp w100">
<option value="0" label="Please Select"></option>
<option repeat-end="onEnd()" ng-repeat="lst in ReportList" value="{{lst.ID}}" ng-selected="lst.ID == DataUploadModel.ReportTypeId">
  {{lst.ReportTypeName}}
</option>
```

> Data type of your `lst.ID` may have impact here.

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PrashantShirke/ADukg/12005/)

Comment: I need this with ng-repeat only.

Comment: any specific reason?

Comment: check updated answer. you need to use `ng-selected` i guess.

Comment: Thanks Prashant it works fine. Actually i am using ng-repeat because i need to initialize datepicker of jquery with div element ID ..so for that i am using here repeat-end="onEnd()" function for calling datepicker

Answer (score 0):

bind list with scope object

```
$scope.DataUploadModel={
ReportTypeId:0;
}
```

Comment: I have written this code at the time edit but not working.                                                 if (response.isSuccess) {
                    $scope.DataPublishModal.ReportypeID = response.result.ReportypeID;}

Comment: but the value you bind is diffrent check onces value="{{lst.ID}} in html

Comment: when you edit the data that time not need to bind individually just write $scope. DataUploadModel=response.data;

Comment: At the time edit i need to set ReportypeID which is saved in another table with reportName,ReportDescription .